# generalized expression required

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, modular-arithmetic, expectation

suppose i have a set  $ {0,1,2.......x-1}$

Now I am generating an i length sequence using the numbers from above set...${a0,a1,....ai}$ where all $ai$$>=0 $ and $ai<=x-1$

Note numbers may repeat in that sequence...so there will be total $x^i$ such sequences.....

Now i am carrying ${a0*a1*.......ai}$ mod $ x $for all such sequences and $i$ get $y0,y1$ ....and $x^i$ such numbers...

What I want is expected value of $y_{i}$ s...can it be generalized for any x and i ?

I am attaching an example also...

let $x=3$...so the initial set= {0,1,2}

now let i be 2

So there will be $9$ such sequences with y values as$ 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2$

so expectation of $y=2/3$

PS: Tell me if any part of the question is not clear...

EDIT1: if no generalized expression, I would like to compute the expectation of y in an efficient manner....so that i don't have to iterate over all possible sequences

Comment: when i=1...it is a straight forward case....avg of y=(x-1)/2 ...

Comment: and one more thing,among x^i numbers of yi there are atleast (x^i-x^(i-1)) numbers are zero

Comment: what else I have noticed is modular multiplication is associative...so all the sequences consisting of same set of numbers will produce same $y_{i}$ values